# $(X)$ faithful flat $k[X,Y]$-module

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to prove that the ideal $(X)$ is a $k[X,Y]$-faithful flat module. I succeeded to prove that it is flat but how to prove faithful flatness? Some hint?

Comment: $(X)$ is isomorphic to $k[X,Y]$ as a $k[X,Y]$-module.

Comment: So every principal ideal $(a)$ of a ring $A$ with $a$ no divisor of 0 is a faithful flat $A$-module?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Wojowu that looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record it as such?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal $(X)$ in $k[X,Y]$ is isomorphic to $k[X,Y]$ as a $k[X,Y]$ through the map $fX\mapsto f$ (since $X$ is not a zero divisor). It follows that for any $k[X,Y]$-module $M$ we have $M\otimes_{k[X,Y]} (X)\cong M$, from which it is easy to see $(X)$ is faithfully flat.